# I would like to find friends child element is present or not in specific parent element like 'Liechtenstein'

Tags: python-3.x

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ss= 'Liechtenstein'
tag_names = set (t.tag for t in root.findall(".//*[@name=ss]/friends"))


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        <friends>
            <frined name="arun" />
        </friends>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I would like to find friends child element is present or not in specific parent element like 'Liechtenstein'

here, tag_names gives empty set. but expecting tag_names=(friends)